# COPY on Redshift always fails with timestamp error despite valid data

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have this data that cannot be imported into my redshift cluster via COPY:

```
"piXKfqz9e54V6n799BYnKSsc2nI="|"e45a2fb9-d0a1-4ffe-bb55-5e91548fbd79"|"\\N"|"2016-08-06 12:34:49"|"2016-08-06 12:34:49"|"impression"|"e45a2fb9-d0a1-4ffe-bb55-5e91548fbd79"|"marketplace_server"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"\\N"|"/lead_dyno/visit_store/140409475"|"lead_dyno"|"visit_store"|"140409475"|"lead_dyno"|"\\N"|"2607:fb90:6847:e17b:1304:2a57:e797:80ed"|"\\N"|"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; LGMS631 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

The error is:

```
Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]
```

The field in question is the 4th one which has the value:

```
"2016-08-06 12:34:49"
```

I have tried basically every flag I can think of trying to get this to import via COPY:

```
copy event from 's3://bucket/test-manifest' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<KEY>;aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET>' removequotes gzip manifest NULL AS '\\N';
```

I've tried adding

```
timeformat 'auto'
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' dateformat 'YYYY-MM-DD'
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
```

I really can't figure out any way to get this row in, and I don't see anything wrong with this data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please post your table definition? SELECT * FROM pg_table_def WHERE tablename = '<your-table-name>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is NOT due to formatting. I tested your data with your copy statement and it worked on my first attempt. Maybe the syntax of your manifest file, the DDL of your table, location of your files in S3.

I just ran a test using your data and it ran fine.

Compare my files to yours, it might help you locate the problem.

Here is what I used:

My table DDL is here:

```
CREATE TABLE tba (
 text1 varchar(256) NULL
,text2 varchar(256) NULL
,text3 varchar(256) NULL
,date01 timestamp NULL
,date02 timestamp NULL
,text4 varchar(256) NULL
) DISTSTYLE EVEN;
```

These is the contents of my data1.txt file

```
"piXKfqz9e54V6n799BYnKSsc2nI="|"e45a2fb9-d0a1-4ffe-bb55-5e91548fbd79"|"\\N"|"2016-08-06 12:34:49"|"2016-08-06 12:34:49"|"impression"
```

Here is my data1-manifest file

```
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://<<my-bucket>>/data1.txt", "mandatory":true}
  ]
}
```

Here is my copy statement (which is basically and copy and paste from yours)

```
copy tba from 's3://rocha-dev/data1-manifest' credentials 
'aws_access_key_id=<<mykey>>;aws_secret_access_key=<<my-secret>>' removequotes  manifest NULL AS '\\N';
```

Below is copied from my PSQL window, which shows successful execution:

```
dev=# CREATE TABLE tba (
dev(#  text1 varchar(256) NULL
dev(# ,text2 varchar(256) NULL
dev(# ,text3 varchar(256) NULL
dev(# ,date01 timestamp NULL
dev(# ,date02 timestamp NULL
dev(# ,text4 varchar(256) NULL
dev(# ) DISTSTYLE EVEN;
CREATE TABLE


dev=# copy tba from 's3://<<my-bucket>>/data1-manifest' credentials 'aws_access_key_id= <<my-key>>; aws_secret_access_key=<<my-secret>>' removequotes  manifest NULL AS '\\N'; 
INFO:  Load into table 'tba' completed, 1 record(s) loaded successfully.
COPY


dev=# select * from tba;
            text1             |                text2                 | text3 |       date01        |       date02        |   text4    
------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------
 piXKfqz9e54V6n799BYnKSsc2nI= | e45a2fb9-d0a1-4ffe-bb55-5e91548fbd79 | \\N   | 2016-08-06 12:34:49 | 2016-08-06 12:34:49 | impression
(1 row)
```

The only material difference between my statement and yours is that I did not use gzip, since I had a single record to load.

Comment: You're totally right. I am still working to figure out what's going on but so far I've found that if I manually edit the file to remove "\\N" and replace it with "\N" the copy works. I'm re-dumping now with "NULL AS '\N'" and will see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I'm there. The last problem I have to deal with is string length. UTF-8 strings, I truncate them to 32 (max length of schema) but they come out at 50+ bytes, which fails to insert via COPY. Any ideas?

Comment: That should be a new question... PostgreSQL string field lengths are measured in characters, not bytes, so there should not be a problem.